# Значение по умолчанию

Tags: html, php

Сейчас реализовано вот так:

```
<select name="s2">
<option disabled><?=$_POST['s2']?></option>
<?=include 'select_val.php'?>
</select>
```

Необходимо доработать,  чтобы значение по умолчанию (в моем случае таковым выступает первая опция) не отображалось в списке выбора при его раскрытии, и первым элементом была пустая строка. Кто что может посоветовать?

```
<option selected> - почему-то не работает. (((
```

Comment: А что мешает её вообще не отображать, а на стороне сервера задать дефолтное значение???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select onfocus="hideDef(this)" onblur="showDef(this)">
<option value="<?=$defaultValue?>"><?=$defaultText?></option>
<?=include 'select_val.php'?>
</select>
<script>
var defVal = "<?=$defaultValue?>";
var defTxt = "<?=$defaultText?>";
function hideDef(x){
    x.options[0].text = '';
}
function showDef(x){
    if(x.value == defVal){
        x.options[0].text = defTxt;
    }
}
</script>
```

Ну, на крайняк, можно просто $defaultText не выводить. Тогда значение по умолчанию будет работать, но пользователь его не увидит.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="s2">
<option value="0" selected></option> 
<option disabled><?=$_POST['s2']?></option> 
<?=include 'select_val.php'?> 
</select>
```

Comment: **`<?=include`** O_O

Comment: что именно вас удивило?) использование отдельного файла или наличие пхп?)
отвечу сразу, если вы о пхп то все просто я с базами из хтмл работать не умею) да и не надежно это все, а по поводу инклуда, а вы напишите запрос из десятка комманд в одну строку, думаю инклуд код украсит только.

зы спасибо за пример помогло но пришлось переделать, что то я не так видимо делал с selected ибо не срабатывала, решение вышло таким

<select name="s2">
  <option></option>
  <option hidden selected><?=$_POST['s2']?></option>
  <?include ''>
</select>

зыы как тут вставлять код?)

Comment: @ToRcH2565 Добавить по четыре пробела перед каждой строкой кода, либо добавить в начале и конце кода символы \`\`. Но лучше в комментарии код не добавлять.

Comment: Имейте ввиду, в самом "замечательном" браузере IE, option disabled не работает.

Comment: хмм, посмотрите на последний листинг, там реализовано без данного кода, надеюсь hidden то работает в IE

еще вопрос практичесски по теме, никогда не сталкивался но просят сделать...

как на странице сделать неактивный скрол при недостаточности материала для его появления, т.е. чтобы скрол справа висел постоянно и автоматически становился кликабельным по мере увеличения материала.

Comment: Вы наверное что-то в этом духе ищете: http://www.tigir.com/javascript_select.htm. Но вообще такие штуки удобнее делать используя ajax, очень просто получается и функционально.

Comment: @shurik, судя по [htmlbook][1]'у disable работает во всех IE кроме 6


[1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/option/disabled